# Create functions to select every second value

Tags: r, dataframe, select

How do I create functions to select every second value in a column in a data frame in R, but from the second value in the column?

I tried something like this:

```
df.new = df[seq(1, nrow(df), 2), ]
```

Comment: What do *you* think is the issue?

Comment: I don't know, but it doesn't give the values I need. Maybe I need to try a different method?

Comment: Do you know what the three arguments you passed to `seq` do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove rows with paired numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70733874/how-to-remove-rows-with-paired-numbers)

Comment: `data.frame(row = seq(5), foo = "foo") |> dplyr::filter(dplyr::row_number() %% 2 == 0)
`

Comment: Thank you. I need the values in a specific column, not the entire row.

Comment: Referring to the `?seq` help page, I'll name your arguments: `seq(from = 1, to = nrow(df), by = 2)`. Then I'll encourage you to guess how to make the sequence start from `2` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `c(FALSE, TRUE)` to subset the `data.frame` and get every second row starting with the second.

```
x[c(FALSE, TRUE),]
#    a b
#2   2 9
#4   4 7
#6   6 5
#8   8 3
#10 10 1
```

And for a specific column:

```
x$a[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
#[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Data

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b=10:1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I need the values in a specific column, not the entire row.

Comment: Then use `x$a[c(FALSE, TRUE)]` for column `a`, as also given in the answer.